# Failed to copy-paste after automatically pasting to the clipboard selected text

Tags: python, windows, clipboard

I wanted to write a program that will paste selected text automatically (for example, no need to use CTRL+C to copy), to the clipboard. My program looks like this:

```
import pyautogui
import win32con
import win32clipboard
import time

def get_clipboard():
    data = ""
    try:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    except:
         r = ""
    try:            
        data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    except:
        r = ""
    try:
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    except:
        r = ""
    return data    
while True:    

time.sleep(1)
try:
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl","c")    
except:
    continue
x = get_clipboard()
if x == "":
    print ("No word in clipboard!")
else:        
    print (x)
```

As you can see, I used autohotkey combination to paste the selected text to the clipboard. This causes failing to normal copy-paste using. If I want to paste selected text with mouse, it will be pasted a blank because my program empty the clipboard.

My question is that how to correct this? Or is there any other way to send selected text to somewhere in the memory that i can reach it automatically?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you making sure the user has selected/highlighted text?

Comment: I use "pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl","c")" to send selected text if exists.Otherwise, it will return an error. By adding try keyword, i got rid of the error. Or I can use event-base programming that detects the double-click event, but i failed to do it.